# PostgreSQL Hierarchical Relationship Functions

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, relation

```
CREATE TABLE sectors
(
    sector_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    sector_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    parent_sector_id integer REFERENCES sectors(sector_id)
);

INSERT INTO sectors(sector_id, sector_name, parent_sector_id)
SELECT 1, 'All sectors', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Business', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Manufacturing', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Retail', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Trading', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Nonprofit', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Agriculture', 1;
```

**Question 1: Find parent relationship via function**

```
SELECT is_parent(1/*All sectors*/, 4/*Retail*/) should be true
SELECT is_parent(2/*Business*/, 4/*Retail*/) should be true
```

**Question 2: Find child relationship via function**

```
SELECT is_child(4/*Retail*/, 1/*All sectors*/) should be true
SELECT is_child(4/*Retail*/, 2/*Business*/) should be true
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Pablo's response...

Using recursive queries, `is_parent()` is going to be *very* fast. Assuming you have an index on `parent_sector_id`, you'll basically do one index scan per depth level.

`is_child()`, by contrast, is going to be extremely slow if you implement it in a naive manner and have a huge tree, aka don't grab all children and checking for your node.

If you've such a tree and occasionally need to retrieve all children, one good option is to implement a pre-ordered tree algorithm (using floats or numerics; not integers, because they tremendously slow down writes) or nested intervals.

If not, simply reverse the arguments and call `is_parent()`, i.e. the sql function `is_child(a, b)` would return `is_parent(b, a)`.

Last but not least, you might want to look into is the [ltree datatype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html) in contrib. Using it, you can do is_parent/is_child queries with a gist index on arbitrary nodes.

Comment: +1 for information about ltree datatype. Sadly, I cannot use it herer. Thanks denis. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to answer that kind of queries, I would recommend you to take a look at [PostgreSQL's recursive queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-with.html). If it's some kind of homework where you need to actually write those functions (`is_parent`, `is_child`) I would also recommend you to implement them using recursive queries.